# Match opening and closing "tags" without creating a second match group

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to capture the content of a specified tag pair which content may include white space and new lines. Here's an example:

```
{section_title}
Section 1 title 
with some white space
{/section_title}
```

I have a regex which does match the content but results in two matching groups:

```
\{section_title\}((.|\s)*?)\{\/section_title\}
```

1. Section 1 title 
   with some white space
2. (the trailing white space)

A variation matches the content without creating a second match group but does not allow the inclusion of nested tags, and I would like to be able to allow that.

```
\{section_title\}([^\{]*?)\{\/section_title\}
```

Is there a way to refactor the first regex to avoid the second match group? I know I can probably remove all "white space only" matches but was wondering if there is a regex-only way.

Also, if possible, I would like to match alternative versions of the tags:

```
{st}
Section 1 title 
with some white space
{/st}
```

It is possible to add the alternatives in capture groups

```
\{(section_title|st)\}((.|\s)*?)\{\/(section_title|st)\}
```

but again I would like to avoid the extra matches. Is this possible?

I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to change `((.|\s)*?)` to `(.*?)` and add `(?m)` to the beginning of the regex, which causes `.` to also match line breaks.

```
str = "{sec_title}\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n{/sec_title}\n"

r = /(?m)\{sec_title\}(.*?)\{\/sec_title\}/
str[r,1]      #=> "\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n"
```

`1` in `str[r,1]` is a reference to what is captured by `(.*)`.

To generalize,

```
str = "{s1}\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n{/s1}\n"

r = /(?m)\{(\w+)\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/
str[r,2]      #=> "\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n"
```

Now  `\1` is a backreference to what is captured by the first capture group, `(\w+)`, whereas `2` is a reference to to what is captured by the second capture group, `(.*)`.

For multiple pairs,

```
str = "{s1}{s2}\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n{/s2}{/s1}\n"

str[r,2]      #=> "{s2}\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n{/s2}"
str[r,2][r,2] #=> "\nSection 1 title \nwith some white space\n"
```

We could wrap this in a method with a variable number of arguments

```
def parse(str, *names)
...
end
```

which we would call

```
parse(str, "s1, "s2")
```

Comment: Switching from `(.|\s)*` to `/m` mode `.*` is good, but I wouldn't be in a hurry to drop the non-greedy modifier. `(?m){name}(.*}{/name}` will match from the first `{name}` to the last `{/name}`, so if there's more than one section with the same name, it will match too much.  If there's only one `{name}` section, but the document is very large, `(.*?)` will tend be much faster than `(.*)`.

Comment: Thanks. @Alan.  I'll trust you on that and put it back in.  The fact of the matter is that I'm only vaguely familiar with HTML!  I made what appears to be an incorrect assumption that all names would be unique.

Comment: Thank you, this is really elegant. Also, thank you for explaining the process step by step!